# Load new data every time component is rendered or use store data

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I'm trying to understand the benefits of Redux pattern coupled together with Angular 2  but one question constantly pops up in my mind.

Let's say I have a dashboard page where I load the most popular products on my website. When I first-time visit this page an API call will be sent to get the products from the server and I store those products in my store. Until now everything is good. From the dashboard page, I click to go to on another page and in few seconds I go back to the dashboard. When I come back to the dashboard page I have some data in the store that I can display to the user. The question is, should I send a new API request to get the most updated data or should I just display data from the store? Here are scenarios we can analyze:

## Display data from the store

If I display data from the store, that data might not be the most updated data that is currently available on the server but I saved one API call. Another question is how and when to update store data or better to say when my store data is invalidated?

## Send API request

On the other side if I send API call every time I go to dashboard then what is the benefit of storing that data in the store (because I'm updating store every time when the component is rendered). This way I always get the most updated data from the API that I then can but I don't have to save in the store because of any way that data will be in the store until I visit my dashboard page again. This way I also contact my API all the time which is not ideal.

## Question

What is the approach you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Redux pattern, then this should be the single point of truth. Meaning that you have to get your data from the store and not directly from the API.

> how and when to update store data or better to say when my store data is invalidated?
>   There are two approaches.

1. Optimistic
2. Pessimistic

The first approach assumes that everything will go well with your server API, and no matter what you persist the data on your store. Think that you send a POST request to persist a product on the DB via the API and the server responds 500. Boom! You have a ghost product on your store.

The second approach assumes that nothing goes well. In the previous example with the product, you won't persist anything on the Store unless you get a 200 response from the API. OR you can add the product on the Store at the first place and delete it if something goes wrong.

Now, in your question, whether you have to send an API request or not is again debatable :)
At the time you are requesting to render the Dashboard component, you send an **Action** LOAD_DASHBOARD_PRODUCTS. This action triggers an **Effect** which in turn sends an API request to the server to get the data. Finally, the **Resolver** changes the State of a particular slice of the Store.
Somewhere in your code, most probably on the onInit() method, you are requesting data from the Store via a particular **Selector**. This Selector is responsible to trigger the action I mentioned earlier.

To answer your question, it depends on the flow you are following to load the Dashboard data. Most of the times I load the Dashboard data every time I load the Dashboard.

Your confusion, however, is very accurate. Why should you use the Redux pattern if you have to send again and again an API request? Well, if your project's complexity is of this scale (Dashboad - products with a simple CRUD page) then the Redux pattern is not the correct choise.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, a lot of the things you wrote is correct. My application is not just dashboard but much more, which gives me a lot of problems just to keep state updated and take care of state data. I'm came to the point to ask myself do I need that because it makes things just more complicated.

Comment: Indeed the Redux pattern requires a lot of boilerplate code. Since your project is not a small one, and If your project's architecture follows the best practices of the Redux pattern then give it one more chance ;)

Comment: If my answer fulfills your questions, please mark it.